# How to make object oriented java project fully generic

Tags: java, oop, generics

Currently in this repo: https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

I use the following code to create a partial brain model:

```
    Neocortex unconnectedNeocortex = new Neocortex(new Region("V1", 4, 4,
            4, 50, 3), new RegionToRegionRectangleConnect());

    LGN unconnectedLGN = new LGN(
            new Region("LGN", 8, 8, 1, 50, 3));

    Retine unconnectedRetina = new Retine(65, 65);

    NervousSystem nervousSystem = new NervousSystem(unconnectedNeocortex,
            unconnectedLGN, unconnectedRetina);

    // connect Retine to LGN
    Retine retine = nervousSystem.getPNS().getSNS().getRetine();
    LGN LGN = nervousSystem.getCNS().getBrain()
            .getThalamus().getLGN();
    SensorCellsToRegionConnect sensorCellsToRegionConnect = new SensorCellsToRegionRectangleConnect();
    sensorCellsToRegionConnect.connect(retine.getVisionCells(),
            LGN.getRegion(), 0, 0);

    // connect LGN to V1 Region of Neocortex
    Neocortex neocortex = nervousSystem.getCNS().getBrain().getCerebrum()
            .getCerebralCortex().getNeocortex();
    RegionToRegionConnect regionToRegionConnect = new RegionToRegionRectangleConnect();
    regionToRegionConnect.connect(LGN.getRegion(),
            neocortex.getCurrentRegion(), 0, 0);
```

You might have noticed that the following code I use above has bad code smell:

```
    Retine retine = nervousSystem.getPNS().getSNS().getRetine();
    LGN LGN = nervousSystem.getCNS().getBrain().getThalamus().getLGN();
```

I would like to fix this by making it into something like this:

```
Retine retine = nervousSystem.get<Retine>();
LGN LGN = nervousSystem.get<LGN>();
```

I was told this was possible but I currently have no idea how to do this. Can someone explain the steps of how I can get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: What you want isn't possible. Probably `getRetine()` should be exposed by the `NervousSystem` `interface`.

Comment: [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) - simple `getRetina` methods on nervous system that pass the request down a single step at a time is one solution. Not having to know about the retina inside nervous system the better one.

Comment: what you are trying to do doesn't really have anything to do with generics, and it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  how do you expect the nervousSystem to know about the retina?  it seems like you want some sort of graph traversal mechanism.  again, nothing to do with generics.

Comment: where is the bad code smell?. All I see is a sequence of objects gets...this is pretty standard

Comment: @JuanManuel the problem is not uncommon but the point is that you hardcode the fact that nervoussystem has a PNS, which has a SNS, which has a Retina into a class that should not need to know the whole object graph. In case you change something there you have to rewrite all the chained calls. http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want some sort of automated graph traversal system (which doesn't have much to do with generics).

Something like:

```
public abstract class BodyPart {

  private List<? extends BodyPart> _linkedParts;

  public <T extends BodyPart> T getPart(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    for(BodyPart part : _linkedParts) {
      if(clazz.isInstance(part)) { 
        return clazz.cast(part);
      }
      T childPart = part.getPart(clazz);
      if(childPart != null) {
        return childPart;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then, assuming all your models extend BodyPart (and their immediate linked parts are added to the _linkedParts List), you could do something like:

```
Retine retine = nervousSystem.getPart(Retine.class);
```

Obviously, this assumes there is a unique result to all links, and no circular links.  If that's not the case, you would have to make the logic a bit smarter (detect circles, return multiple results, etc).